# sql, join 2 Tables

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, join

I have 2 tables

matchdata:
id_team1, id_team2, name_team1, name_team2, group_order_id

teams:
team_id, team_name

I try this:

```
select * from matchdata join teams on matchdata.id_team1 = teams.team_id;
```

But I need

```
matchdata.id_team1 = teams.team_id
```

AND

```
matchdata.id_team2 = teams.team_id
```

after that I want `select WHERE group_order_id = $bla`
How can I do that?

Comment: did you consider not storing the names in matchdata, but just retrieving them from teams when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `JOIN` on a single table.

```
SELECT * FROM matchdata
JOIN teams t1 ON matchdata.id_team1 = t1.team_id
JOIN teams t2 ON matchdata.id_team1 = t2.team_id
WHERE group_order_id = $bla;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM matchdata md 
    JOIN teams t ON t.team_id IN (md.id_team1, md.id_team2)
WHERE md.group_order_id = $bla
```